# How to resize a LWJGL Window without distorting rendered objects

Tags: java, opengl, window, lwjgl

I have a problem with resizing the window.
Currently i am always changing the values in the `GLU.gluPerspective()` when changing the window size.

---

In those two examples i've used these values for the Perspective `GLU.gluPerspective(70F, this.windowWidth/this.WindowHeight, 0.05F, 1000.0F)` and only changed the window size.

[LWJGL Window size = 1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WWNE.png)

[LWJGL Window size = 1080x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EDcl.png)

As you can see it just looks good when the window size is 1080x1080 Pixel.
But i don't want to change the values every time when i wan't a other window size.

I hope you can understand me and know what i want.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple. `1920/1080` becomes `1` because you're doing integer division. This is why 1080 x 1080 looks good, because that aspect ratio is actually `1`.

What you want is:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(70F, 1920F/1080F, 0.05F, 1000.0F)
```

It is typical to not hardcode the aspect ratio, but rather pull the values from the window:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(70F, (float)width / (float)height, 0.05F, 1000.0F)
```

That way the aspect ratio is correct no matter the window size.